# Combobox.Visible property not working

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, combobox, textbox

Evening, I have the following code, in a static class which helps my userInterface partial class. Whenever i get to the the section which checks if either the combobox/textbox is visible:

```
if (cb.Visible == true)
```

&

```
if (tb.Visible == true)
```

its always false even if the controls are visible on the form.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
public static bool VerifyTableLayoutControlsContainData(TableLayoutPanel tlp)
    {
        foreach (Control input in tlp.Controls)
        {
            ComboBox cb = input as ComboBox;
            if(cb != null)
            {
                if (cb.Visible == true)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cb.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            TextBox tb = input as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                if (tb.Visible == true)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

**Edit1:**

UserInterface code

```
    private void uiBtnDataVerification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (VerifyingData != true)
        {
            AllInputsContainDataCsvFileVerificationStage = true;
            //Check all inputs have something in them
            InputsContainDataCsvFileVerificationStage();

            if (AllInputsContainDataCsvFileVerificationStage == false)
            {
                UiHelper.UpdateLog("One or more inputs has not been specified.", uiTxtOperationLog);
                return;
            }

            ...
        }
        else
        {
            //Cancel permanent cancellation token.
        }
    }

    public void InputsContainDataCsvFileVerificationStage()
    {

        ....

        if (UiHelper.VerifyTableLayoutControlsContainData(uiTableLayoutPanelColumnDataTypes)) { }
        else
        {
            AllInputsContainDataCsvFileVerificationStage = false;
        }

        ....
    }
```

Original code is in the UiHelper class

**Edit2:** As per Toms suggestion i have made the following changes

```
public userInterface()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        uiTableLayoutPanelColumnDataTypes.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(notifyMe);
        uiCBColumn1DataType.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(notifyMe1);

        SortedColumnNames = new List<TextBox>();
        SortedDataTypes = new List<ComboBox>();
        AllInputsContainDataCsvFileVerificationStage = true;
    }

    public void notifyMe1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool temp = uiCBColumn1DataType.Visible;
        MessageBox.Show("its been changed");
    }

    public void notifyMe(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool temp = uiTableLayoutPanelColumnDataTypes.Visible;
        MessageBox.Show("its been changed");
    }
```

before clicking the button, i checed what cb1 visibility property was set to and it was True. I still get false when i try to check via the original method.

im stumped!!

**Edit3:**

It seems that when i click on the second tab, the comboBox's visible property = false.

Does anyone know why this might be??

Comment: Are there subclasses of combobox in the form?

Comment: Code worked with the exception on the ComboBox, I had to add a check for a `SelectedIndex > -1` check.  *When* are you calling this routine?

Comment: I click a button to execute some verification of a file. This code is run just before i create a task.

Comment: can you try to catch the event [visibleChanged] : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged.aspx

Comment: @Tom i tried to catch the event and show a message box each time it was changed. I get two messageboxes appearing just after the form has loaded. Ive been though the Designer.cs but i cant find anything in there which states that the TLP.visible is true or false. Any ideas?

Comment: The TableLayoutPanel control has to be visible on the screen when you run your verification code.  If it's behind an inactive TabPage, then it isn't on the screen.

Comment: @larsTech yeah someone on SO chat had just hinted at the same thing. Can u please put that as the answer and i will mark it as the accepted one. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Final solution was to delete the tlp's or to just use the enabled property instead of visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my comment:

> The TableLayoutPanel control has to be visible on the screen when you run your verification code. If it's behind an inactive TabPage, then it isn't on the screen and the control will report the Visible property as false, regardless if the property is set to true in the designer.